# Why is UWP crashing after adding CarouselView?

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms.carouselview

Can someone explain me why UWP is crashing after adding CarouselView to ContentPage. Am i missing some library (on UWP) for rendering or?

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which `CarouselView` you have used, is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/introduction) one?

Comment: And please try to delete bin and obj folder and  rebuild your uwp project again.

Comment: Yes, I was/am trying to use that CarouselView. I've tried deleting bin and obj folder, but the problem remained.

Comment: Btw, I had the same issue while adding Xamarin.Forms Map, but the issue was sold by one single line in MainPage.Xaml.Cs. Now I'm wondering is there anything I need to add in MainPage.Xaml.Cs in order for CarouselView to be rendered and shown? Kind regards and thank you for helping me so far.

Comment: Well, please try to edit uwp project target and min version to others.

Comment: Do u try to set ItemsSource on CarouselView (or any elements inside it) before it is Visible? In my project this causes exactly same problem.

Comment: Apparently, this crash was made by bindingContext which was initialized in ContentPage.BindingContext in xaml designer, but not in constructor of xaml.cs page.  Now it's resolved. Thanks guys for help!